# Outlook 365 add-in created with angular8 cannot delete cookie created with ngx-cookie-service

Tags: angular, cookies, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

I've created an office 365 add-in for outlook.

I'm using Angular8 for the add-in and using ngx-cookie-service to store my authentication token details in the cookie.

I can install the add-in, store the auth token in the cookie and use token stored in cookie to make my service calls. But somehow the outlook desktop client does not delete the cookie using the usual methods (delete cookies in edge, clear outlook cache).

If I use the browser, the behavior is as expected. When I delete cookies (in all of IE Edge, FF and Chrome), I'm asked to login again. Outlook desktop client though just redirects me to the home page

Any suggestions what I could be missing?

Comment: Assuming your addin is a taskpane add-in, can you try clearing the cache using the F12 developer tools? Launch your add-in, then open up a command prompt window, launch C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe, then in the F12 window that opens up, select your add-in's HTML page, navigate to the Network tab, then click on the Clear Cache button (button no. 5 from the left). The icon for this button looks like a window with a red 'x' at the top-left corner.

Comment: That works! Is there a solution that might be easier for non-technical folks? Will need our client delivery team to explain this process really well to end users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion by  Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT works as expected